# Rewrite rule that doesn't work

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following dynamic URL: http://www.lakaweb.com/dev/cserv/index.php?a=list&car=C5&year=2012&engine=1.8-HDi

in which I rewrite to http://www.lakaweb.com/dev/cserv/list/C5/2012/1.8-HDi

with:

`RewriteRule ^dev/cserv/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/(.*)/?$ /dev/cserv/index.php?a=$1&car=$2&year=$3&engine=$4 [L]`

Now, when I wanna add another field at the end, why doesn't this rewrite rule work:

```
RewriteRule ^dev/cserv/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/(.*)/?$ /dev/cserv/index.php?a=$1&car=$2&year=$3&engine=$4&service=$5 [L]
```

Comment: How exactly doesn't it work? Does it match?

Comment: I guess so, since I can't print out the service-variable? I tried activate the rewrite log, but it's all empty..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `([^/\.]+)` Matches the '.' in `1.8-HDi` as the end of one of the fragments. The rule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^dev/cserv/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /dev/cserv/index.php?a=$1&car=$2&year=$3&engine=$4&service=$5 [L]
```

Tested [HERE](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)

Comment: The last field is numbers only btw.

Comment: The reason why it didn't work is correct... Give me a minute and I'll try and revise :D

Comment: It works on my local machine... and on the website I linked. The `([^/]+)` matches everything up to `/` (4 times), and the `([0-9]+)` Matches all the numbers at the end (though you could use `([^/]+)` if you wanted to). `/?` will take care of the slash at the end. It's correct... I don't know what's up with your machine :(

Comment: Hmm.. It suddenly works if I turn off some of the other rewrites.. :-/

Comment: Ah, you had other rewrites, as a general rule, put the rewriterules from most specific to general, otherwise they interfere with each other. Glad you got it figured out. (also, since you have multiple rules like this, try and avoid ending them with `(.*)`

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Thanks for the help! =)